# Speed up live search js, php, mysql

Tags: php, javascript

I have made a "live search bar" with php and javascript. if you enter a word in the search bar it searches the database (mysql).

index.php:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="getMovie(this.value)"/>
<div id="movie"></div>
```

javascript.js:

```
function getMovie(value) {
$.post("getmovie.php",{partialMovie:value},function(data) {
    $("#movie").html(data);
});
}
```

getmovie.php:

```
include_once "connection.php"; 

if($_POST['partialMovie']){
    $partialMovie = $_POST['partialMovie'];

    $sql = "SELECT title FROM movie WHERE title LIKE '%$partialMovie%'";
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stm->execute(array());
    while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
    }
}
```

This works, but it is way to slow. I have only 3 "movies" in my database, but it takes like a second or two to show the results.

the titles of the 3 movies are: een twee drie.
but if i type "een" fast, after a second you see een, twee, drie. a second later you see: een twee. and another second later you see: een.

So my question is: is there a way to speed the search up or is there a way to stop searching if you type another letter?

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Did you tried to set index for `title` field in MySQL?

Comment: Why don't you profile the request and see what part is taking the longest and go from there. But 1 second is not that bad at all, factor in round trip times etc.

Comment: @MrD I know that one second is not that bad, but if you type a word of 12 letters, it takes 12 seconds, and that is to long. And now there are only 3 records in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Either lower your expectation, because 1 second for a request's round trip is not very improvable, or get the data as json at page load time and search against locally available json data. But if there are many records this might not be an option.

Answer (score 0):

As you use PDO, bind your parameters to avoid sql injection.

Then use full text search in MySQL (select match against), it will be a lot faster than the like %% approach.

Doc : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="movie-autocomplete"/>
<div id="movie"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#movie-autocomplete').keyup(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.post(
                "getmovie.php",
                {
                    partialMovie: $(this).val()
                },
                function(data) {
                    $("#movie").html(data);
                }
            );
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

This will create a small delay and post an atual value within the field.

**PHP**:

```
include_once "connection.php"; 

if(!empty($_POST['partialMovie'])){
    $partialMovie = $_POST['partialMovie'];

    $sql = "SELECT title FROM movie WHERE title LIKE :movie ORDER BY title LIMIT 0, 10";
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stm->execute(array(':movie' => "%{$partialMovie}%"));
    while($row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<li>".$row['title']."</li>";
    }
}
```

We have to bind the parameter to secure the SQL query and **prevent SQL injection**. Also You should ensure You have set the PDO to use real prepared statements.

To further speed all the process You should return only JSON data from the PHP and fill in the `<ul>` within Your JS code...

Comment: your "prepared statement" won't work and index won't help with leading %

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have repaired the statement so it should work now.

Comment: tried it, but i get an error: "uncaught typeerror cannot call method toLowerCase"

Comment: I am not calling `toLowerCase` anywhere... If You had added it - check for mistyping errors... Anyway, `typeerror` is not a native PHP error nor exception so check You code where the exception is thrown.